# Can "backup" be used as a verb in the context of data management?

Tags: verbs, technical, computing

I have heard *backup* being used as a verb in the sense of

> I have to *backup* my hard disk

by non-native English speakers (the English noun *backup* is also used in other languages, for example in German, so it may be a false friend). The correct expression seems to be

> I have to make/create a backup of my hard disk.

I know that "to back up" is correct English, but has a different meaning.

Microsoft uses "back up" in the above sense, see [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore), but the Oxford and Miriam-Webster dictionaries do not seem to support this use.

Has *to backup* (or *to back up*) become part of the English language?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/back_up: 5 (idiomatic, computing, transitive) To copy (data) as a security measure.
    *Back up your documents folder before applying the update.*

Comment: Thanks @Jim, I had not considered wikipedia to be a reliable reference in this matter. However, I believe that in this case it does suggest that "to back up" is quite widely used in the above sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

> Has *to backup* (or *to back up*) become part of the English language?

Certainly it has. You can Google your way to millions of further examples on the Web.

Your question also draws attention to the phenomenon whereby some computing-related phrasal verbs consisting of verb + preposition are being treated by many people as single merged entities, at least in the present tense. Thus *to back up* becomes *to backup*, and *to log in* becomes *to login*.

The ultimate result of this incipient process may be that the past tense of these novel verbs will also change (or at least become widely accepted), e.g. *she backed up her hard drive* may become *she backupped her hard drive*; *they all logged in at the same time* may become *they all loginned at the same time*.

At my time/space coordinates, Googling *backuped* already garners about 360,000 hits, and *backupped* about 22,000. Similarly, *logined* accounts for some 127,000 hits, and *loginned* about 40,000.

It will be interesting to see what happens.

Comment: You raise an interesting point. Let me mention that "downloaded" is widely used in German instead of the verb "herunterladen", and that its past participle is "gedowngeloadet" instead of "heruntergeladen".

Comment: *backuped, logined, loginned* are clearly incorrect: *backed up, logged in.* One can google "xaxaxa" and bring up 1,340,000 results.

Comment: @Kris - Currently they are non-standard usages (and to that extent I agree with you), but my point was that eventually they might *become* standard usages as the language continues to morph. Incidentally, I Googled xaxaxa just now and got only 514,000 hits, of which the majority on the first couple of pages at least relate to a music band of that name.

Comment: Likewise, people using *setup* (as a verb) instead of *set up*. Drives me nuts. But you're right that language evolves...

Comment: http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=101442

Comment: I have closevoted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter for judgement, but I recommend that you use *back up*.

The usual derivations of *back up* are *backed up* and *backing up*. *backupped* and *backupping* exist, but they are not common, and [you won't find them in print](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=backupping%2C+backupped&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=). So in most cases, *back up* is the correct form.

But if you find yourself in in a community where *backupped* and *backupping* are the norm, then go ahead and write *backup* without a space.

Answer (score -1):

**backup** *n.*
**back up** *v.* *pt:* **backed up**

> The verb form is to **back up** in two words, whereas the noun is backup.
>   … Every backup scheme should include dry runs that validate the reliability of the data being **backed up**. ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup))
>
> … why you need to **backup** your data
>   … If you have not yet **backed** up your hard drive, now is a good time to do so. It's much better to **back up** your data now than once it is too late. ([techterms](http://www.techterms.com/definition/backup))
>   [emphasis mine]

Do not use  <strike>*backupped*</strike>  for the past tense.

Comment: Your own posting contradicts itself: "The verb form is to **back up** in two words, whereas the noun is backup". "...why you need to **backup** your data". Or am I missing some subtle point?

Comment: @ErikKowal They are two different sources.